# How should I react to a question with personal information?

Tags: support

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49759466/5468463) via the "Help and improvement" queue. I think that some personal information is used, and it should not have been.

Am I right or am I overreacting? Is the fact that it's rotated makes it matter less? Should I flag this with a special flag to ask the question to be deleted as closing would not make it disappear?

Comment: To make things more interesting, the European GDPR directive will probably mean that SO is not allowed to store this image in their database, since the person mentioned in the picture probably doesn't have any connection with SO. Though that probably doesn't apply to American citizens.

Comment: link to "this question" leads to 404

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[It does legitimately look like a storefront.](https://www.fairgrass.com/)  The contact phone number matches up with the phone number on the shipping label, so the likelihood of this leaking *personal* information is very low.  It's not information I'd personally want blasted out on the internet, so I'd presume that the store owner would have a "conversation" with their developer.

I personally wouldn't see this as rising to the cause of a moderator *needing* to remove this information.  I'd instead focus on the question itself; it's far too broad and my energies are better spent voting that to close than hailing a moderator right now.